# How to open a Chrome Profile through Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-profile

My script I have been writing has been working great. I just added the option so it would open a profile on chrome using this code.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\princess\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
options.add_argument(r'user-data-dir=C:\Users\princess\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 1')
```

When used, I get this error code.

```
C:\Users\Princess\Desktop>CHBO.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Princess\Desktop\CHBO.py", line 12, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\princess\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
  File "C:\Users\Princess\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    desired_capabilities = options.to_capabilities()
TypeError: to_capabilities() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 15):

To *create* and *open* a new *Chrome Profile* you need to follow the following steps :

- Open *Chrome* browser, click on the *Side Menu* and click on *Settings* on which the *url* `chrome://settings/` opens up.
- In *People* section, click on *Manage other people* on which a popup comes up.
- Click on *ADD PERSON*, provide the *person name*, select an *icon*, keep the item *Create a desktop shortcut for this user* checked and click on *ADD* button.
- Your new profile gets created.
- Snapshot of a new profile **SeLeNiUm**

[image: SeLeNiUm]

- Now a desktop icon will be created as **SeLeNiUm - Chrome**
- From the properties of the desktop icon **SeLeNiUm - Chrome** get the name of the profile directory. e.g. **--profile-directory="Profile 2"**

[image: profile-directory]

- Get the absolute path of the *profile-directory* in your system as follows :

  ```
  C:\\Users\\Otaku_Wiz\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 2
  ```
- Now pass the value of *profile-directory* through an instance of *Options* with `add_argument()` method along with key *user-data-dir* as follows :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\AtechM_03\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 2")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
  driver.get("https://www.google.co.in")
  ```
- Execute your `Test`
- Observe *Chrome* gets initialized with the *Chrome Profile* as **SeLeNiUm**

[image: SeLeNiUm]

Comment: What should I do with this part?

Comment: C:\\Users\\Otaku_Wiz\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 2

Comment: Windows! Yikes! If you're looking for the profile and on Linux, go to /home/{user}/.config/google-chrome. For me, it created a "Profile 1". If you're on Mac, go to Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome (so I'm told)

Comment: This has nothing to do with what he asked

Answer (score 3):

You can use `options = Options()` or `options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()` at place of `options = webdriver.ChromeOptions`

Otherwise you are pointing at an object (namely `webdriver.ChromeOptions`), and not making an *instance* of that object by including the needed parenthesis

Comment: it did open a browser with the profile I wanted but didn't open the sites and navigate as the code is written. I got this back in CMD

Comment: :ERROR:cache_util.cc(134)] Unable to move cache folder C:\Users\princess\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ShaderCache\GPUCache to C:\Users\princess\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ShaderCache\old_GPUCache_000
[30224:11480:0314/012119.198:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(169)] Unable to create cache
[30224ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(601)] Shader Cache Creation failed: -2
[30224:11480:0314/012119.342:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(120)] Failed to launch GPU process.
Created new window in existing browser session.

Comment: Then it says this:

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed

Comment: @OtakuWiz this is the answer to your question. the answer to your new question is this part of the error message `Created new window in existing browser session`. You have to close Chrome before running your python code. [see here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15311/adding-user-data-dir-option-to-chromedriver-makes-it-not-work-and-timeout-only)

Comment: This is correct but poorly formatted and unexplained