# Selenium Chromedriver Error Loading Profile

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to load a user profile to chromedriver. It pops up a browser window with the right profile, but then crashes before it loads the web page.  I've attached the code and the vague error message.  Can you please let me know what I'm doing wrong?  I've searched stackoverflow and it seems like this should work.  Thank you!

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data") 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriverdir, chrome_options=chromeOptions)
browser.get('https://www.yahoo.com')
```

Error:

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-b1d95c22d006> in <module>()
     23 #chromeOptions.add_argument('window-size=1920x1200')
---> 25 browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriverdir, chrome_options=chromeOptions)
     26 browser.get('https://www.yahoo.com')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.pyc in __init__(self, executable_path, port, chrome_options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path)
     67                 command_executor=ChromeRemoteConnection(
     68                     remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url),
---> 69                 desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
     70         except Exception:
     71             self.quit()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.pyc in __init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector)
     96             warnings.warn("Please use FirefoxOptions to set browser profile",
     97                           DeprecationWarning)
---> 98         self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
     99         self._switch_to = SwitchTo(self)
    100         self._mobile = Mobile(self)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.pyc in start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    186         parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps,
    187                       "desiredCapabilities": capabilities}
--> 188         response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    189         if 'sessionId' not in response:
    190             response = response['value']

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.pyc in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    254         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    255         if response:
--> 256             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    257             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    258                 response.get('value', None))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.pyc in check_response(self, response)
    192         elif exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException and 'alert' in value:
    193             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, value['alert'].get('text'))
--> 194         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    195 
    196     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.39.562718 (9a2698cba08cf5a471a29d30c8b3e12becabb0e9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Comment: Check this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270109/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-python/49280195#49280195

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried that first and it did not work...

Comment: I think your problem is with chromedriver. 
Did you double check path or you may also change the version of driver, sometimes version of driver doesn't work for particular browser

Comment: It's the latest chromedriver (chromedriver=2.39.562718) and the path is correct since it loads the correct profile, but crashes before loading the webpage