# python using selenium, error: chrome unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is **not** a repost of

[selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed with ChromeDriver and Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112188/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-chrome-fa)

I am using Linux and creating a new profile is **not an option**. I want to load an **existing profile** (not create a new one) just like selenium gui can.

I am able to get chromium to function, but not google chrome. Chrome will open but will kick back an

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /opt/google/chrome/chrome unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0
```

error.

I am trying to start google chrome with user directory access, so I can capture existing sessions.

code that fails:

```
option.add_argument("user-data-dir=/home/user/.config/google-chrome/Default/") #)PATH is path to your chrome profile
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/google/chrome/chrome', options=option)
```

code that works but launches chromium and not google-chrome:

```
option.add_argument("user-data-dir=/home/user/snap/chromium/common/.cache/chromium/Default/") #)PATH is path to your>
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver', options=option)
```

I'm sure I am using the correct executable

[image: htop]

I'm pretty sure I have the correct chromedriver driver install

```
root@Inspiron-laptop:/home/user# pip3 install chromedriver-autoinstaller
Requirement already satisfied: chromedriver-autoinstaller in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (0.2.2)
```

Just using it incorrectly.

How do I launch google-chrome from within selenium while accessing cache directories?

I am on Ubuntu 20.04

UPDATE:

Full script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import random

minptime = 25
maxptime = 120

class MyweClass(BaseCase):
        def method_a():
                option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
                option.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
                option.add_argument("--mute-audio")
                option.add_argument("user-data-dir=/home/user/.config/google-chrome/Default/") #)PATH is path to your chrome profile
                driver = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/google/chrome/chrome', options=option)
                driver.get("https://world.com/myworld")
                print(f'driver.command_executor._url: {driver.command_executor._url}')
                print(f'driver.session_id: {driver.session_id}')
                time.sleep(18)
                return driver
driver = MyweClass.method_a()
```

UPDATE II:

Same error using

```
option.add_argument("user-data-dir=~/.config/google-chrome/Default/")
```

and

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome', options=option)
```

and

```
chmod -R 777 /home/user/.config
```

To ensure user was hitting cache directory as user.

Google chrome info:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### *Thumb rule*

> *A common cause for Chrome to crash during startup is running Chrome as **`root`** user (**`administrator`**) on Linux. While it is possible to work around this issue by passing `--no-sandbox` flag when creating your WebDriver session, such a configuration is unsupported and highly discouraged. You need to configure your environment to run Chrome as a regular user instead.*

---

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436382 (70eb799287ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac),platform=Linux 4.15.0-109-generic x86_64)
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

As per your *code trials* seems you are trying to access a *Chrome Profile* so you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\path\\to\\your\\profile\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 2")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
  driver.get("https://www.google.co.in")
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of detailed discussions in:

- [How to open a Chrome Profile through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270109/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-python/49280195#49280195)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed with ChromeDriver and Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112188/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-chrome-fa/52112468#52112468)
- [How to use Chrome Profile in Selenium Webdriver Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394408/how-to-use-chrome-profile-in-selenium-webdriver-python-3/52399027#52399027)
- [Selenium: Point towards default Chrome session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344560/selenium-point-towards-default-chrome-session/56401979#56401979)

Comment: i'm not starting as root. the path for my cache should have cleared that question up.

Comment: I apologize, i spoke too soon. Same issue.