# InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value error while opening website

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to open a website in my default browser with selenium but I can get it to work.

My code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\\\Users\\rober\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\\\Users\\rober\\OneDrive\\Skrivebord\\Bot\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)

driver.get("https://www.zalando.dk/jordan-air-jordan-1-mid-sneakers-high-joc12n001-a18.html")

buyButton = False

while buyButton is False:

    try:
        
        addToCartBtn = addButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/x-wrapper-re-1-6/div/div[4]/button')

        print("Varen er udsolgt")

        time.sleep(1)
        driver.refresh()

    except:
        addToCartBtn = addButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="picker-trigger"]')

        print("Varen er på Lager")
        buyButton = True

while buyButton is True:
    time.sleep(1)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.uc-btn#uc-btn-accept-banner"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Vælg størrelse']"))).click()
    driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//label[starts-with(@for, 'size-picker')]//span[text()='51.5']"))))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[starts-with(@for, 'size-picker')]//span[text()='51.5']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Læg i indkøbskurv']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[title="Indkøbskurv"]'))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".z-coast-base__totals-tile .z-1-button__content"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[title="Registrér dig"]'))).click()
```

My Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir
```

I think the error has something to do with `\` but I can not figure it out.

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session for either of the following reasons:

- There are previous instance of [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727887/what-is-benefit-of-using-chromedriver-over-webdriver-if-we-are-using-only-chrome/53744026#53744026) process attached to the system memory.
- You have a manually opened [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) session already running.

You need to initiate the execution of your program with a clean slate.

---

Further, while working with [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) ***v3.x***, [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) and [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) on [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) you may need to pass the argument `executable_path` along with the *absolute path* of the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727887/what-is-benefit-of-using-chromedriver-over-webdriver-if-we-are-using-only-chrome/53744026#53744026) binary through  either of the following options:

- Double back slashes i.e. `(\\)`
- Single back slash i.e `(\)` along with the raw `(r)` switch.
- Binary extension i.e. `(.exe)`

So you have to change the line :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\\\Users\\rober\\OneDrive\\Skrivebord\\Bot\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
```

with :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\rober\\OneDrive\Skrivebord\\Bot\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
```

or :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\rober\\OneDrive\\Skrivebord\\Bot\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
```

> You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:
>
> - [How to use Chrome Profile in Selenium Webdriver Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394408/how-to-use-chrome-profile-in-selenium-webdriver-python-3/52399027#52399027)
> - [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed with ChromeDriver and Selenium
>   in
>   Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112188/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-chrome-fa/52112468#52112468)
> - [Selenium: Point towards default Chrome session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344560/selenium-point-towards-default-chrome-session/56401979#56401979)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer but it's not working I still get the same error message