# Is it possible to run tests in an existing browser session?

Tags: cypress

Normally, whenever I open Cypress and run tests, it loads another Chrome window with a new session. I want it to utilize an existing Chrome window or its session instead of starting a new session from scratch. Is this possible with Cypress?

Comment: I want to ask you why do you want to run your tests in a separate browser's session?
Cypress creates its separate browser profile and its not possible for cypress launching it with the current browser profile.
This answer will explain to you how profiles work with selenium: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61303603/how-to-work-on-a-exist-session-in-selenium-with-python/61305083#61305083

Comment: The question had nothing to do with selenium.  And the user is trying to do just the opposite; (e.g., run subsequent tests from the same session).

Comment: You can make a script that will move the second window to the first one. Should not be difficult

Comment: How are you running cypress?
What do you mean existing chrome window?