# Automate DOM interactions within browser w/o development server

Tags: javascript, frontend, automated-tests, playwright, end-to-end

I want to send automated interactions to my React app using an API similar to the Cypress or Playwright E2E testing APIs, which allow, for example, clicking on an element, waiting for an element to exist, checking various conditions.

Typically a tool like Cypress would run a browser as a subprocesses, run the tests within, and then close the browser.

I want to instead use the API as a library and run both the testing code (calling Cypress) and the target application to test within the same webpage (browser context).

Is it possible to use the Cypress API (or something similar to it) to accomplish this?

Comment: Just curious but why? What limitations are you running into with playwright?

Comment: Example: Interactive demos, a-la Storybook, but with simulated clicks on the app.

Comment: Maybe [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) might do the trick ?

Comment: But what exactly is the problem of the browser being used "for the purpose of the integration test"? That's what integration testing is: you don't use "some random brower", you _configure_ exactly what you're testing, and every time you run it, it's the same: your test is deterministic, because it's a test. You _don't_ want to run things in a random browser that's already open, that's not testing, that's... I'm sure there's a term for it, but it's not proper testing. Demoing? Maybe?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Demoing. But also testing.

Comment: No. Those are two separate things. Testing is what "just happens". It runs, your involvement is not necessary, it has to run, and then tell you the result: it passed all tests, or it failed 1 or more. Demos are just "running your program and making it do things automatically to show things off". It's not integration testing, your tests better have passed before you start a demo.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Indeed they are two different things. I am trying to build end to end tests that also act as demos. However, I care more about the "Run something like Cypress or Playwright within an existing DOM (embedding within my React app)" than I do the "slow it down so it acts as a demo" part.

Comment: Then please update your post to not call this testing, because testing really is a completely different thing, and calling it that muddles the question.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't feel like you're understanding my messages. I want to use one of the end-to-end testing APIs like Cypress directly within the browser without a separate dev server. It's related to the e2e testing libraries.

Comment: You don't use a dev server for testing: your tests run as part of your CI, e.g circlci, jenkings, github actions, etc. It runs _unattended_. What you then do with the code that you know works, because it passes your tests, is up to you, and isn't testing. That's just "using your code" (which can include running demos). Including "running those same tests with the browser set to not close", which is an option offered by cypress, playwright, etc.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans There is the Orthodox way to do this, and then there is the actual question I am asking. They are two different things. I understand that you are trying to solve the X Y problem here. But I am aware of the typical way this is done and am asking specifically how to run Cypress directly within an existing browser session. If I wanted to do it the normal way there would have been no need to ask a stackoverflow question. Please accept that some of us are trying to do things that aren't exactly the normal way at times.

Comment: Then just tell playwright to open the browser "and leave it open" so you see your tests happening. I.e. tell it to not run "headless".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Perhaps my wording wasn't clear enough, but I'm directly asking how to run these in an existing browser session without a separate dev server or chrome instance. I want to load Cypress as a library and pass it a DOM node and run tests within that node.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I rewrote the question and title. Hopefully that makes it clearer. The original wording was a bit confusing.

Comment: The use case isn't clear to me here either.

Comment: Then hopefully someone else can help because it sounds like you want to do something that no integration framework was designed for, or can even be used for. Their core design principle is to offer a clean browser for proper testing, running in a "dirty" (in the technical sense) browser would completely defeat that purpose. So I suspect you're going to have to write your own solution here.

Comment: It might not be clear to you but that doesn't change the validity of the question as a technical exercise, nor does it invalidate the use cases I've mentioned for running a sub-instance of an app within a page as a demo or an embedded test during development.

Comment: If you don't explain why you're doing the technical exercise, then the question is off-topic. We're interested in [practical questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). How is Playwright supposed to connect to a random browser and start automating it? Is this random browser on your machine, or on a different machine? I don't think this is a thing, but if you don't mind explaining what you're trying to accomplish, there [may be another way to do it you haven't considered yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).

Comment: @ggorlen I've explained it a number of times here. The purpose is to be able to interact with an instance of the app in an automated way, outside of the context of e2e testing. This could be used for either interactive demos or embedded e2e tests. I already mentioned that this is not an X-Y problem situation above.  Funny you link that. I've been using StackOverflow for over 10 years and am quite familiar with the XY problem. This is not it. If there's a better way to automate interactions with an app without a development chrome instance let me know or feel free to edit my question.

Comment: Your explanation seems to be just repeating the question and don't really get to the heart of the goal. What would the interactive demos look like from the user's perspective? If the user has a DOM, you want them to be able to watch Playwright or Cypress modifying it in real time? This user is a random visitor to your site, or you on your own machine? You want to do this because you're trying to create an app that does ... what, exactly? The XY problem occurs when you're asking if it's possible to do a very unusual thing without explaining why, exactly what appears to be going on here.

Comment: That makes more sense, although I still don't know who's consuming this app. If it's a client on a random web browser, you probably can't connect Playwright to them, but if it's a developer locally, you can maybe arrange this by running the automated browser on the storybook component. If you want to trigger actions on a component, can you use the browser API, like `document.querySelector(".foo").click()` and so forth?

Comment: I don't really want to argue, but nobody has "rushed to close" this, and there's no condescension intended from my end. There are 0 downvotes and 0 close votes at present. I'm trying to understand your use case so I can actually write an answer. If I can't understand it, then I'll vote to close it. ChatGPT will never ask any critical questions, just spit out some random garbage code that doesn't fix the issue. I guarantee you ChatGPT will be unable to help you.

Comment: @ggorlen That would work. However, Cypress has a nice API for doing these interactions and waiting for expected results to occur (like a component appearing or other conditions). I was asking the question here hoping there was a way to load Cypress within an existing DOM as a library - since it's JavaScript anyway, it should be able to run entirely within the browser, communicating with the DOM within the same process instead of IPC. But perhaps this is not possible currently, and I need to go look at the internals of Cypress to figure this out. If it's not possible, I can accept that.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but I understand your use case. I suggest editing it into the question so there's clear motivation for the unusual request. Good luck.

Comment: @ggorlen I understand where you're coming from and hesitated to ask for this reason. But you're right; GPT has no good ideas on this topic and nor do I. Was hoping someone on SO knew of a way to accomplish this correctly. Thanks for the advice. I'm not sure how to edit the question to be clearer but will try my best to come up with a better way to ask this.

Comment: @ggorlen I have found an answer: https://testing-library.com/docs/ supports this, so does https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library - I did find one other question where this was asked in the past but was closed for lack of clarity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62135486/is-it-possible-to-run-tests-in-an-existing-browser-session - answered here, hopefully this is useful to anyone who runs into the same question I did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77392850/431369

Comment: I did find a case where someone else thought of this: https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples - react-dnd has in their docs that their examples also act as a set of end-to-end test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[testing-library](https://testing-library.com/) provides a common API for sending interactions to the DOM and checking the results.

> The core library, DOM Testing Library, is a light-weight solution for testing web pages by querying and interacting with DOM nodes (whether simulated with JSDOM/Jest or in the browser). The main utilities it provides involve querying the DOM for nodes in a way that's similar to how the user finds elements on the page. In this way, the library helps ensure your tests give you confidence that your application will work when a real user uses it.

[react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/) adds additional support for querying the state of React components.

These libraries support running within the browser without an attached e2e test runtime (like Playwright).