# chromedriver wont get website python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I want my program to open up the default chrome profile and then get youtube.
I can make it either open youtube (in a new chrome browser), or open the default chrome profile, but not both.
(And no im not running both driver variables)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time


print('starting')
print('getting driver')


exec_path= "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"               # exec path from chrome://version

profilePath= 'C:\\Users\\MyName\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1'      #profile path from chrome://version

chromePath= 'C:\\Users\\MyName\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Python programming\\chromedriver.exe'  #path to driver



options= webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument(profilePath)
print('options add argument...')

### Run one or the other ###
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= chromePath , options=options) #gets youtube
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= exec_path, options=options) #gets chrome profile


print('webdriver getting youtube...')
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
```

when I run the driver line that gets the chrome profile I get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\MyName\OneDrive\Documents\Python programming\Web automation\webAuto.py", line 24, in 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= exec_path, options=options) #gets chrome profile
File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in **init**
self.service.start()
File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 104, in start
raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Answer (score 0):

As per your question and your code trials if you want to open a Chrome with the customized Chrome Profile, Try using below code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('C:\\Users\\MyName\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1' )
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\\MyName\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Python programming\\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
```

Here you will find a detailed discussion on [How to open a Chrome Profile through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270109/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-python)