# User data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I am trying to run start Chrome using Selenium I am getting an error as:

```
  File "C:/Users/Ilya/PycharmProjects/University_BOT/Selenium/main_Second.py", line 20, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Ilya\PycharmProjects\University_BOT\Chrome\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
  File "C:\Users\Ilya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Ilya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Ilya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Ilya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Ilya\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open a Chrome Profile through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270109/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-python)