# I am trying to launch chrome specific profile using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to launch chrome specific profile using python selenium

I try this code

`option.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Gamer\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 2")`

but it's open chrome as a Guest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it as below, For the profile location type `chrome://version` in the URL bar and check for `Profile Path`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Gamer\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Profile 2')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in")
```

Also, try to close the main browser instance while running it for multiple time else it might display the Exception

Answer (score 1):

You can try with options like this :

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Gamer\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 2")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in")
```

Comment: i see this,
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 16-17: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Can you share the entire stack trace  ?

Comment: sry, i didn't understand (i am not 100% english)
did you mean the code ?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270109/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-python

Comment: i try to do that but same
my code is 
```options = Options()
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 2")
web = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe', options=options)```

Comment: @SatyendraSharma : No it ain't, read carefully the two answers.